# Stopping SocketServer with blocking handle

Tags: python, python-multithreading, tcpserver

I'm using `SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn`, pretty much as in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins).

Other than having extracted the clients to run on their own script, I've also redefined the `handle` method as I want the connection to the client to keep alive and receive more messages:

```py
def handle(self):
    try:
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break # Quits the thread if the client was disconnected
            else:
                print(cur_thread.name)
            self.request.send(data)
    except:
        pass
```

The problem is that even when I try to terminate the server with `server.shutdown()` or by `KeyboardInterrupt`, it will still be blocked on the handle as long as the client maintains an open socket.

So how I can effectively stop the server even if there are still connected clients?

Comment: Post the code that is calling the handle function, please.

Comment: Please see https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#asynchronous-mixins ; I've only extracted the clients into a separate script and changed the handle; everything else is the same as in the docs.

Comment: Do you have server_thread.daemon = True in your code? If not, it will not exit when interrupting until the thread is finished.

Comment: Please, post the exact code you have so i can test it myself.

Comment: Please see the two files: http://pastebin.com/ZAths2w5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72253/discussion-between-stian-ok-and-joao-goncalves).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was to use `SocketServer.ForkingMixIn` instead of `SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn`.

This way the daemon actually works, even though using processes instead of threads was not exactly what I wanted.